Flip applications between multiple screens (maximized)
I have a dual-monitor setup with my MacBook Pro screen as the secondary monitor and an external monitor as the main one. I keep several apps maximized, like Chrome and Teams.
I usually keep Teams on my secondary monitor for quick glances at incoming messages. I also put things I don't use often there, like the terminal.
However, when I need to focus on something more complex, like reading a long message or replying, I'd prefer to have Teams on my main monitor.
It's a hassle to move it with the mouse every time. Is there a keyboard shortcut (that I can set up) to switch Teams between monitors while keeping it maximized? Ideally, I could switch it back with the same shortcut after I'm done.
Thank you for your kind help!

The free app Rectangle offers the ability to move a window from one display to another. It also provides plenty of other options for window management.

